# what happens to static variables when the application pool recycles?

Tags: asp.net, iis, global-asax

I am setting a static variable in application_start of global.asax. 
And I read that application_start does not trigger after a recycle.
Does the recycle mean I lose the value of static variables?
Are there any other events that get triggered after recycle?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that people who are saying application_start doesn't trigger after a recycle are wrong.
I set my my app pool recycle interval to 2 minutes and added this code to my application_start

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("App Start", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

And I see it every 2 minutes in the logs. You can also click the recycle button in IIS too to test it.